# MySQL Query help for hiking organization

Tags: mysql

I have to make a query inside my Database for a hiking organization:
--> How many hikers, older than 70yrs, have joined the hike, named "Pohod na Triglav", which was organised by the "Planinsko društvo Planinec" organization?

The relational schemes are as follows:

```
    CREATE TABLE Hikers(
    IDHiker INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    Sex ENUM('male', 'female'),
    BirthDay DATE NOT NULL,
    Phone VARCHAR(45)
    );

//table for joining hikers and hikes (includes foreign keys)
    CREATE TABLE Hiker_has_joined_the_Hike(
    IDJoin INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Hikers_IDHiker INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Hikes_IDHike INTEGER NOT NULL
    );

    CREATE TABLE Hikes(
    IDHike INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Type_of_hike_IDType_of_hike INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Name_Hike VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    No_of_available_hikers INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Time_of_beginning DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Time_of_end DATETIME NOT NULL
    );

//table for joining organizations and hikes (includes foreign keys)
    CREATE TABLE Organization_organizes_a_Hike(
    IDOrganization INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Organizations_IDOrganization INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Hikes_IDHike INTEGER NOT NULL
    );

    CREATE TABLE Organizations(
    IDOrganization INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Title VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    Short_title VARCHAR(45),
    E_mail VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    Phone VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
    );
```

So far I got this, but it displays 2 of them, but only one should be in there..:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Hikers.IDHiker) AS No_of_joined_above_70
FROM Hikers, Hiker_has_joined_the_Hike, Hikes, Organization_organizes_a_Hike, Organizations
WHERE ((Hikers.IDHiker = Hiker_has_joined_the_Hike.Hikers_IDHiker) && (Hiker_has_joined_the_Hike.Hikes_IDHike = Hikes_IDHike) && (Hikes_IDHike = Organization_organizes_a_Hike.Hikes_IDHike) && (Organization_organizes_a_Hike.Organizations_IDOrganization = Organizations_IDOrganization) && ((YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(Hikers.BirthDay))>70) && (Hikes.Name_Hike='Pohod na Triglav') && (Organizations.Title='Planinsko društvo Planinec'));
```

Sorry everyone..the query i uploaded was in my language..i translated it for better understanding now..as i did with the creates

Comment: At first glance, I'd say you'd want to start by using proper JOINS.  That would probably resolve your issue (and you could then safely drop the DISTINCT statement too).

Comment: Sturgus, I was thinking the same thing, but I see very little referential integrity.

Comment: use INNER JOIN and mention correct table and column name in query

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the distinct should be inside the count.
With explicit join it looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Planinci.IDPlaninca) AS Stevilo_Udelezenih_Planincev_Nad_70
FROM Planinci
    inner join planinec_se_je_udelezil_izleta 
        on Planinci.IDPlaninca = planinec_se_je_udelezil_izleta.Planinci_IDPlaninca
    inner join Izleti on planinec_se_je_udelezil_izleta.Izleti_IDIzleta = Izleti.IDIzleta
    inner join drustvo_organizira_izlet on Izleti.IDIzleta = drustvo_organizira_izlet.Izleti_IDIzleta
    inner join Drustva on drustvo_organizira_izlet.Drustva_IDDrustva = Drustva.IDDrustva
WHERE ((YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(Planinci.Rojstni_Datum))>70) 
      && (Izleti.Naziv='Pohod na Triglav') 
      && (Drustva.Naziv='Planinsko društvo Planinec');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MySQL supports DISTINCT inside your COUNT aggregate function.  For an output of solely the number of hikers that fit your criteria, your statement of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Planinci.IDPlaninca) AS Stevilo_Udelezenih_Planincev_Nad_70
FROM Planinci, planinec_se_je_udelezil_izleta, Izleti, drustvo_organizira_izlet, Drustva
WHERE ((Planinci.IDPlaninca = planinec_se_je_udelezil_izleta.Planinci_IDPlaninca) && (planinec_se_je_udelezil_izleta.Izleti_IDIzleta = Izleti.IDIzleta) && (Izleti.IDIzleta = drustvo_organizira_izlet.Izleti_IDIzleta) && (drustvo_organizira_izlet.Drustva_IDDrustva = Drustva.IDDrustva) && ((YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(Planinci.Rojstni_Datum))>70) && (Izleti.Naziv='Pohod na Triglav') && (Drustva.Naziv='Planinsko društvo Planinec'));
```

Would turn into something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Hikers.HikerID) AS PohodHikersCount
FROM Hikers 
INNER JOIN HikersOnHikes ON Hikers.HikerID = HikersOnHikes.HikerID
INNER JOIN Hikes ON HikersOnHikes.HikeID = Hikes.HikeID
INNER JOIN Organizations ON Hikes.OrganizationID = Organizations.OrganizationID
WHERE Organizations.OrganizationName = 'Planinsko društvo Planinec'
    AND Hikers.HikerName = 'Pohod na Triglav'
    AND Hikers.HikerAge > 70;
-- (or " AND YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(Hikers.BirthDay))>70;" if that's how your ages work...)
```